# Google Scripts - Creating a script that runs every seconds

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a script that runs every 10 seconds in google scripts, but I haven't found any method to do that,

My Code is running every minute:

```
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("refresh") 
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(1)
  .create();
```

I've tried this javascript's setInterval method:

```
setInterval(function(){ /*do*/ }, 10000);
```

However, set interval is not defined.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: is there an answer :(

Comment: You can do .everyMinutes(0.1)?  Just a random thought.

Comment: No can't. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time based triggers only let you run scripts at 1 minute intervals and, unfortunately, that cannot be changed.

Comment: Thank you for answer. is it mean there is no any method to do that?

Comment: I've been thinking about this and running into the same issue. But would it be possible to create a chrome/safari extension that could trigger the add-on?

Comment: You can publish your Google Script as a web app and make a GET or POST request to that app from the Chrome extension.

Comment: Okay! Thanks. I fiddled around a little more and figured client-side triggering is probably the best and easiest way forward.

Answer (score 0):

Any JS written for Google Apps Script is executed server side. Because it is a free service, they make it difficult to take much server-side compute time. But because you can trigger these scripts from the browser, if all that you're writing is an add-on, then write the timer in your html files, as they will be executed by the client.

For instance, in my code.js script file I might have the following function:

```
function appendHello() {
    DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection().appendText("Hello! ");
}
```

And in my html for my add-on (with imported JQuery), I've placed the setInterval method there instead:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        setInterval(function() { google.script.run.appendHello(); }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```